# Selecting HTML tags according a condition

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML document with elements that contains id tags with values inside. I trying to select all tags with ids that their value is bigger from a certain number

Example: I want to select all rects their id is > 2

```
<rect id='1'></rect>
<rect id='2'></rect>
<rect id='3'></rect>
```

I saw many examples and i didn't find one that fit my requirements.
I thought about something like that:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id]')
```

But i have no idea how to write the condition inside.

[EDIT]

I forgot to mention that i want only those elemnts that contains class name of `ocrx_word`
I tried to run thet

```
  const wordId = document.querySelector('[bbox=' + '"' + pageOneWord + '"' + ']'[0]);
        const rects = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ocrx_word[data-num]')]
        const wantedIds = rects.filter(({id}) => Number(id) > word)
        console.log(wantedIds)
```

But i receiving

```
document.querySelectorAll(...).slice is not a function
```

Comment: The error is the `.slice()`, but you aren't calling `slice` anywhere in the code, as far as I can see?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No. Its referring to Spread operator   `const rects = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ocrx_word')]`

Comment: The spread operator does not invoke `slice` - the code as posted shouldn't result in the error you describe

Comment: I successfully picked the wanted rects, but when i tried to filter them it sayng rects.filter is not a function . `let word = document.querySelector('[bbox=' + '"' + pageOneWord + '"' + ']'[0]);
        const rects = document.querySelectorAll('.ocrx_word[id]')
        const wantedIds = rects.filter(({id}) => Number(id) > word)
        console.log(wantedIds)`

Comment: You did not convert the NodeList to an array - you have to do that in order to call `filter` on it. (see the code in the answer - I spread the NodeList into an array to achieve that)

Comment: Yes I understand, but as i call the spread operator  it giving me: `document.querySelectorAll(...).slice is not a function `

Comment: Spread syntax should not call `slice` - if it does, your interpreter (or browser engine) is broken. I cannot reproduce the problem - press "Run code snippet" in my answer. What spread does is it calls the `[Symbol.iterator]` method on the object - `Array.prototype.slice` is not involved (and `NodeList.prototype.slice` does not exist). You can also convert to an array by passing an array-like object to `Array.from`

Comment: @CertainPerformance It worked with `Array.from`. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set and perform math conditions inside a query string, but you can select all tags which have an `id` attribute, then filter by whether the attribute, coerced to a number, fulfills your condition:

```js
const rects = [...document.querySelectorAll('rect[id]')];
const filteredRects = rects.filter(({ id }) => Number(id) > 2);
console.log(filteredRects);
```

```html
<rect id='1'></rect>
<rect id='2'></rect>
<rect id='3'></rect>
```

That said, numeric indexed IDs are pretty strange, and are probably a code smell in most situations - IDs should probably indicate something *absolutely unique* and singular, usually. If you want to associate each `rect` to a number, perhaps use a data attribute instead:

```js
const rects = [...document.querySelectorAll('rect[data-num]')];
const filteredRects = rects.filter(({ dataset: { num }}) => Number(num) > 2);
console.log(filteredRects);
```

```html
<rect data-num='1'></rect>
<rect data-num='2'></rect>
<rect data-num='3'></rect>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use your suggestion but i am facing an issue. Please view the edits inside my question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.ocrx_word')].filter(x=>+x.id>2)
```

```js
let n=[...document.querySelectorAll('.ocrx_word')].filter(x=>+x.id>2)

console.log(n);
```

```html
<rect id='1' class='ocrx_word'></rect>
<rect id='2' class='ocrx_word'></rect>
<rect id='3' class='ocrx_word'></rect>
<rect id='4' class='abc'></rect>
<rect id='a' class='ocrx_word'></rect>
```